# Calculating User Values c#

Tags: c#

How do I calculate two values given by user in c#

- How much money do you have? x
- Price of a product? y

Ending up with:
You have enough money to buy X products, you will have X left afterwards

I know how to ask the questions, but how to then calculate the values.

Comment: I would use division.

Comment: You could use multiplication. You are getting these unhelpful comments instead of downvotes because your question is extremely vague

Comment: You have $5.00.  Candy bars are $1.50.  How would _you_ determine how many candy bars you can buy?  How do you know how much you will have left over?

Comment: @KMC: Please refrain from personal attacks. They are not appropriate on StackOverflow, and in no way help the poster or the community.

Comment: please do not criticize or make downvote for new users, it's his first day at StackOverflow.

Comment: @AbdellahOUMGHAR  I agree with not criticizing in a mean way, but I believe this is the exact type of question that should be downvoted.

Comment: @GendoIkari you're right, but I prefer to be lenient with new users.

Answer (score -1):

Elementary school arithmetic returns the correct result.

```
Tuple<int, decimal> calculate(decimal money, decimal price)
{
    int buy = (int)Math.Floor(money / price);
    decimal left = money - buy * price;
    return new Tuple<int, decimal>(buy, left);
}
```